# Why does Sherlock hate his father so much in Elementary?

Tags: character, analysis, elementary

I understand that Sherlock does not like his father (Morland Holmes) very much because he was a distant father as a child. But this does not seem to be a strong enough factor for Sherlock's venomous hate for Morland.

Why does Sherlock hate his father so much?

Comment: How much of the show have you watched?

Comment: I've seen it all, up to the latest episode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sherlock's hatred of his father is explained in Elementary Season 4, Episode 14 titled "Who Is That Masked Man".  During that episode as Sherlock is investigating the death of Sabine he reveals to Joan that he blames his father for his mother's death.  His father threw her out and due to prenuptial agreement she was living in a small rundown house that caught fire one night, killing her.  There are several recaps available online.  Later in the series Morland reveals why he threw her out.

[Elementary Season 4 Episode 14](http://www.ew.com/recap/elementary-season-4-episode-14)

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that one... Didn't even realise!

Answer (score 0):

Probably what Mykewlname mentioned is the base of Sherlock's attitude towards his father, but there are a couple of secondary facts that play their role as well, such as:

1. Sherlock was sent to a boarding school at the age of eight
2. Morland's job & personality (as portrayed by Sherlock at least): wealthy international consultant with no morals, willing to do anything for money & power
3. Morland seems to have a tendency to favor Sherlock's elder brother, Mycroft.

Source:
[Morland Holmes from Elementary Wiki](http://bakerstreet.wikia.com/wiki/Morland_Holmes)